# Perl CSV without exponential

Tags: perl, csv, biginteger

I am generating CSV, and I want to store numbers without exponential format.

Please give me some suggestion.

I tried:

1. I used , perfectly,
2. I tried single quote before the large number, so I got as expected out in CSV, but number fore it showed single quote, if I click that number then number displaying perfectly.
3. I tried with delimeter, that is `'` quote before one trailing slash.

So far no luck.

Comment: Do you mean that the contents of the file should not use scientific notation? Or do you mean for Excel to display each value without scientific notation?

Comment: Show examples of the numbers you are having problems with and how you want them to look.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using something like the Math::BigInt module:

```
 use Math::BigInt;
 my $num = new Math::BigInt(2);
 $num=$num**128; 
 print "$num\n";
```

which will output:

```
 340282366920938463463374607431768211456
```